# Split Jenkins pipeline into environment part and stages part as a template

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

We use a Jenkins server to create multiple iOS/Android projects with Unity and Xcode. At the moment we have a single Jenkins file in each root directory of our project repositories with the entire configuration and build steps in one file:

```
pipeline {
  agent any

  environment {
    REPOSITORY_URL = 'ssh://git@XYZ.git'
    PROJECT_SUBDIR = ''
    BUILD_FOR_ANDROID = 'true'
    BUILD_FOR_IOS = 'true'
    UNITY_VERSION = '2018.4.0f1'
  }

  // how to load this from a template file? -->
  stages {
    stage('Checkout') {
      steps {
        script {
          if (env.PROJECT_SUBDIR) {
            env.PROJECT_DIR = sh(
              script: "echo ${env.WORKSPACE}/${env.PROJECT_SUBDIR}",
              returnStdout: true
            ).trim()
          } else {
            env.PROJECT_DIR = sh(
              script: "echo ${env.WORKSPACE}",
              returnStdout: true
            ).trim()
          }
        }

        // more stuff ...

      }
    }
  }
  // <--
}
```

Is it possible to load the part "stages" from another file (e.g. a template) during the build process? This would separate the project-dependent configuration part from the common "stages" part and I could update the build process for all project repositories in a single or versioned template file?

How would it work with the environment variables? Are they still in the same context or do I have to pass them?

Comment: are you familiar with shared libraries https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/ ?

Answer (score 2):

That was a good advice.

I managed it by using the last approach mentioned on this page:

https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#defining-declarative-pipelines

So I copied my pipeline in my groovy file called

```
/vars/run_pipeline_template.groovy
```

in my new repository. Before that I called it pipeline.groovy which wasn't my best idea because that is a protected keyword. I left the definitions of my environment variables in the former Jenkinsfile. They can still be accessed by env.VAR_NAME without the need to forward them to the library script. The library is in its own Git repository and I added this library to the Jenkins configuration in section Global Pipeline Libraries. And this solves the version problem as well, because you can define which branch/tag/hash is used when importing the library template in the Jenkinsfile.

Thank you.